# Buildfire: Plugin Functions on Android But Not On iOS

Tags: mobile

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuQrC.png)We have a plugin deployed on the buildfire platform that is a standalone model. We use OAuth from the login screen presented upon accessing the plugin within our app. This plugin is made up of API calls into one of our vendor partners platforms. The entire plugin is written using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It functions perfectly on Android devices and in testing from Windows PCs, however, iOS devices do not work. Using the same credentials, verified on an Android device, iOS devices immediately throw a login error. Need direction on what might be causing this. Login code in post. [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpoBQ.png)

```js
function setToken() {
    let header = document.getElementById("loginHeader");
    let user = document.getElementById("username");
    let pw = document.getElementById("password");
    const bodyText = 'grant_type=cloud_contact&username=' + user.value + '&password=' + pw.value;
    console.log(bodyText);
    fetch('https://example.cloud.com/oauth/token', {
            method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            timeout: 0,
            mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            },
            body: bodyText
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            header.innerHTML = 'logging in...';
            let token = data.access_token;
            if (token) {
                authManager.enforceLogin();
                buildfire.userData.save({ token }, "myToken", (err, result) => {
                    if (err) console.log("error in setToken(): " + err);
                });
                header.innerHTML = "Login successful";
                console.log('login successful and token saved successfully');
            } else {
                header.innerHTML = "Login failed";
            }
        })
        .then(noObject => {
            navHome();
        })
        .catch(error => console.log('try again', error));
}

function loggedIn() {
    console.log("checking login...");
    authManager.enforceLogin();
    buildfire.userData.get("myToken", (err, response) => {
        if (err) console.log('login error in loggedIn(): ' + err);
        if (response) {
            if (!response.data.token) {
                navToLogin();
            }
            console.log("we have a response token");
            fetch('https://example.cloud.com/api/userinfo?token=' + response.data.token, {
                    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.timeout: 0,
                    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(result => {
                    let contexts = result.contexts;
                    buildfire.userData.save({ contexts }, "contexts", (err, result) => {
                        if (err) console.log("error saving contexts: " + err);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => redoLogin('error using token to verify login', error));
        }
    });
    return checkLogin();
}

function checkLogin() {
    var retVal = true;
    buildfire.userData.get("myToken", (err, response) => {
        if (err) console.log('error in checkLogin(): ' + err);
        if (response) {
            console.log("we have a response token");
            fetch('https://example.cloud.com/api/customers/0/activity/search?token=' + response.data.token, {
                    method: 'GET', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.timeout: 0,
                    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .catch(error => redoLogin('error using token to verify login', error));
            console.log("token is valid");
            retVal = true;
        } else {
            console.log("invalid response");
            retVal = false;
        }
    });

    return retVal;
}

function redoLogin(message) {
    console.log(message);
    logoutAndNavToLogin();
}

function console.log(data) {
    let logBox = document.getElementById("logBox");
    if (logBox) {
        logBox.innerHTML += 'Log: ' + data + '. ';
    }
    console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="../../../scripts/buildfire.js"></script>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="page-header text-center text-info" id="loginHeader">Enter your BoldNet credentials</p>
        </div>
        <form action="setToken()">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <p class="text-muted">Username:</p>
                    <input class="form-control" id="username"></input>
                    <p class="text-muted">Password:</p>
                    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password"></input>
                </div>
                <form-button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="setToken()">Login</form-button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div>
            <p id="logBox"></p>
        </div>
        <script src="login.js"></script>
        <script src="nav.js"></script>
        <script src="authManager.js"></script>
        <script src="dal.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific [iOS devices immediately throw a login error]

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like an issue with BuildFire OAuth since it does not seem to be using BuildFire OAuth but rather a custom code setting user data to the standard BuildFire login user.

You can troubleshoot by creating a testing version of the plugin with some logging on the UI to see where it is exactly failing on iOS.

Here is also link that explains how to integrate with BuildFire OAuth 2 https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/using-oauth2-sign-in-integration/

Comment: Yes, we are using our own login, separate from the Buildfire login. Did the logging setup and have it working. Android works as it did before. On the iOS devices we are just seeing "load failed" in the logs.

Comment: Update to iOS. We were able to log an error. The message pops up "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." Does this help identify anything? I have added a screenshot above in the original post of this issue.

Comment: @JesseMorgan this could indicate a certificate authority issue on iOS. Can you test it in an iOS Safari browser and see if you still get the same error ? If so that will give more insight on the reason of the error

Comment: We verified the addresses on our end were whitelisted on the API server end. I am stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: We are seeing this on Safari vs Chrome and may be indicative of what the difference is between iOS and Android. "Blocked a frame with origin "https://plugninserver.buildfire.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://app.buildfire.com". Protocols, domains and ports must match.

Comment: @JesseMorgan This probably means the plugin is accessing parent app when it shouldn't, for example accessing the parent window object of the app or accessing app resources from the plugin. check what network calls it is doing to app.buildfire.com from the plugin